# InnerHTML Code override

Tags: html, innerhtml

Basically, my host has put a user agreement on my footer without my permission, they are not prepared to remove it yet. It seriously affects my SEO due to the heavy repeat words...

I am poo with coding but i understand the basics... All i have to edit is HTML and I've found that innerHtML works good too! I have worked out that it is a `<DIV>` I am able to write a basic code that extracts all that info onto the page rather than on a small pop up box...it is progress but not what I want. I need it gone, not hidden but gone!

Here is the call to action and file (I believe) I've managed to find in the dense code -

```
function zfl_CookieWarning(id){zfl_Control.prototype.constructor.call(this,id);var markup=$
```

That I can see is the call to action and there the file it is calling " ZFL_CookieWarning

I need help in writing something that I can pop in to HTML that disables/get's rid of it completely...

I have currently used the "...googleoff: index..." feature active as so it doesn't damage my rankings further...

Much appreciated...

P.s. I don't have access to the complete coding file all I can do is submit a code and it overrides the overall code for that bit. Nor do i have access to the jQuery etc files

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: You should probably consider switching hosts, rather than battling them :)

Comment: Hiding it wont prevent it from being indexed - but I see you are using the googleoff tagging - so that will help for Google at least. That said, you should really just consider moving hosts. Any paid host that injects adverts into a site without the site owners permission is just plain sketchy.

Comment: Up most agreement that you should consider switching hosts. You can also try changing your current `<del><!--googleoff: index-->...<!--googleon: index--></del>` for `<script type="text/x-ignoreme">...</script>` watch out for breaking JavaScript actions on the page.

Comment: Or even just commenting out the block with `<!-- ... -->`.

Comment: Cheers all! I am waiting on a response. To be honest I think they have put themselves in a legal pickle as they have now a lot of complaints and users wanting to leave due to that sneaky move.